# JSONObject["caption"] not found

Tags: servicenow, form-designer

We are using form designer of servicenow to change elements on a form.

The table used to create the form is extended by the task table and contains a workflow with approvals and various stages.

When we try to change something within form designer, it does not matter what it is, renaming a field from summary to summarys for instance and clicking save.

The action gives this error:

**JSONObject["caption"] not found**

Only some forms are affected by this issue, for instance incident forms, change forms all open and can be changed and saved.

I have a feeling that this error is related to a known issue but i just wondered if anyone on here has seen it.

NB:  It is not possible to share my JSON response because it's all done behind the scenes by servicenow. I am in a form design view and I am simply clicking save on a form change

Thank you for your time

Comment: Can you post how your JSON is structured? If I had to guess at this point, `caption` is not at the root level of the object you are accessing.

Comment: No I am sorry I am not posting any xml response here. All I am doing is changing a value on a form and clicking save.

Comment: So that no one else votes me down, it is not possible to share my JSON response because it's all done behind the scenes by servicenow. I am in a form design view and I am simply clicking save on a form change

Answer (score 0):

This has now been resolved.

Turned out a title on a form header had more than 40 characters and this was causing the error on form save.

Max limit on a title